# can't run Daemon::Control perl script as root. @INC not correct (perlbrew)

Tags: perl, perlbrew, start-stop-daemon

I've written a [`Daemon::Control`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Daemon::Control) script in perl, which I can start/stop as a service from the user, but now I want to have this run on reboot.
When I run as a user all is well, when I run it as root, it fails with

```
Can't locate Mojo/Server/Morbo.pm in @INC
```

I run the command with *service appname start* , this works fine.
root has a basic perl installation, then the user has a perlbrew install with all the correct modules.

Shouldn't `Daemon::Control` run as the user if I specify "user" and "group",  and I also specified the init_config to the users .bashrc file to setup the environment variables.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Daemon::Control;

use Cwd qw(abs_path);

Daemon::Control->new(
    {   name        => "appname",
        lsb_start   => '$syslog $remote_fs',
        lsb_stop    => '$syslog',
        lsb_sdesc   => 'appname startup Short',
        lsb_desc    => 'Morbo , bit lighter than hypnotoad.',
        init_config => "/home/mojouser/.bashrc",
        path        => abs_path($0),

        program => '/home/mojouser/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin/morbo',

        program_args => [
            '-l', "http://*:3000", '-w', '/home/mojouser/apps/appname/lib',
            '-w',
            '/home/mojouser/apps/appname/templates',
            '/home/mojouser/apps/appname/script/app'
        ],

        user  => 'mojouser',
        group => 'mojouser',

        pid_file    => '/tmp/mojouser_appname.pid',
        stderr_file => '/tmp/mojouser_appname.err',
        stdout_file => '/tmp/mojouser_appname.out',

        fork => 2,
    }
)->run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The user's perlbrew environment is not set up when morbo is called this way. perlbrew is activated from the users' shell rc but all [Daemon::Control](https://metacpan.org/pod/Daemon::Control) is doing after the double fork is setting $ENV{HOME}, $ENV{USER}, see the source for [double_fork()](https://metacpan.org/source/SYMKAT/Daemon-Control-0.001006/lib/Daemon/Control.pm#L186) in [Daemon::Control](https://metacpan.org/pod/Daemon::Control)

Mojolicious uses `#!/usr/bin/env perl` for the shebang line in morbo to correctly use the perl specified by the environment. In this case though, you don't want the perl specified by the environment but the users' perlbrew perl.  If you change the first line of `/home/mojouser/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin/morbo` to `#!/home/mojouser/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin/perl` it should work as expected.

Comment: Sorry just re-read your question and saw the mention of init_config did you do: `your_daemon_control_script.pl get_init_file > /etc/init.d/appname`? It looks like init_config is only used then.

Answer (score 0):

Often your env as a user holds environment variables needed to properly execute some sub-process while the env for root contains very little. I've solved this by $ENV{whatever} = 'something'; in the Daemon::Control->program.
Others recommend that be done in /etc/init.d/program instead. FWIW